# Can't open file from intent in Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-intent, filechooser

I'm trying to access a file from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, when I try it on my device (which is Android 8), it works perfectly fine. But then, when I try it on my friends' device (Android 10), it's not working. When I try to open the file from Word it keeps say that "Can't open file. Try saving the file on the device and then opening it." And when I open a pdf file, it doesn't show anything, just black screen.

btn_add OnClick Listener

```
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] mimeTypes = {"application/vnd.google-apps.document", "application/pdf", "application/vnd.google-apps.form",
                    "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation", "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                    "application/x-excel"};
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
                if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                }
            } else {
                String mimeTypesStr = "";

                for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
                    mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
                }
                intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0, mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
            }                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    });
```

onActivityResult

```
                titleArrays = new ArrayList<>();
                ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(titleArrays);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("Id: ", ""+id);

                hashMap.put(id, data.getData());
                returnCursor =
                        getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
                nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                titleHashmap.put(id, returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
                for (int i : hashMap.keySet()){
                    titleArrays.add(new ItemProperty(hashMap.get(i), titleHashmap.get(i)));
                }
                img_file.setImageResource(0);

                id++;
                // Item OnClick
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position) {
                        Log.d("Position: ", ""+position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, titleArrays.get(position).getUri());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

I wonder what did I do wrong. If you guys know it, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: It gives me this error java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10310 does not have permission to content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D3%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3D0huJ%2BMSuwMH3cstbogu7g7%2BHKQjxkLP6pchnrv2JLOOCNO0it1rWtCVxgCW76g%3D%3D [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Comment: Then you do not have the rights to grant to other apps to be able to view the content. Perhaps switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Also note that you do not need `| Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` in your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent`. Those flags are for granting permissions to other apps, not for requesting permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally solved this by following [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) instruction! I added `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`
to my `Action_VIEW` `Intent`and changed my `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

btn_add OnClick Listener

```
    String[] mimeTypes = {"application/vnd.google-apps.document", "application/pdf", "application/vnd.google-apps.form",
                    "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation", "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                    "application/x-excel"};
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
                if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                }
            } else {
                String mimeTypesStr = "";

                for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
                    mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
                }
                intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0, mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

onActivityResult

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                titleArrays = new ArrayList<>();
                ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(titleArrays);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("Id: ", ""+id);

                hashMap.put(id, data.getData());
                returnCursor =
                        getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
                nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                titleHashmap.put(id, returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
                for (int i : hashMap.keySet()){
                    titleArrays.add(new ItemProperty(hashMap.get(i), titleHashmap.get(i)));
                }
                img_file.setImageResource(0);

                id++;
                // Item OnClick
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position) {
                        Log.d("Position: ", ""+position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, titleArrays.get(position).getUri());
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```